# 403 Permission Denied when exporting subscriber list

Tags: newsletter, permissions

I am getting **permission denied when attempting to export a csv list of subscribers.** XML works fine. I am guessing there is a file that needs permissions updated.

**I just can't find it.**

Thanks.!

Comment: Give permission to your var/* folder and clean cache.

Comment: Thanks BornCoder. I made sure all permissions on var and sub directory's were 755 and files within var were 644. Deleted cache. Still no success.

Comment: Did you checked in which folder CSV file is creating ??